# Memory allocation in C++ STL for dynamic containers

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, reference, stl

When you declare 2D arrays, they are stored in contiguous memory locations and this is easy as the number of rows is fixed while declaring them.

Whereas when we declare a 2D vector `vector<vector<int>> v`, how does it work. As the number of rows is not fixed at all. My first guess was the new vector which you push_back into it are randomly allocated but then even that wont work as these vectors of int are randomly accessible.

My first guess is to allocate vectors of int randomly in the memory and store their address in another vector of addresses.
eg

```
vector<vector<int>> vmain;

vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> b = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> c = {1, 2, 3};

vmain.push_back(a);
vmain.push_back(b);
vmain.push_back(c);
```

is stored something similar to

```
vector<&vector<int>> vmain; //vector of pointer to vector

vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> b = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> c = {1, 2, 3};

vmain.push_back(&a);
vmain.push_back(&b);
vmain.push_back(&c);
```

Please tell me if this is the correct way.

And also for vector of maps or sets `vector<map<int, int>> v1` and `vector<set<int>> v2`. As size of maps and sets is not fixed.

Comment: The second example you give won't even compile.  It will compile if the declaration of `vmain` is changed to `vector<vector<int> *> vmain`.

Comment: I meant it be passed as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector object doesn't store the elements. It stores a pointer to a contiguous chunk of memory containing the elements. When you have `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` the outer vector contains a pointer to a contiguous chunk of memory containing vector objects, each of which have a pointer to a contiguous chunk of memory containing the ints.

`std::map` and `std::set` also don't store the elements in the object itself. Each object contains a pointer to a BST containing the elements.

Comment: So does it mean that in a 1D vector, there is an array which stores the addresses of memory locations at which the actual data is stored.

Comment: @AbhayPatil No. The data is stored in one contiguous chunk and there is a pointer storing the address of that chunk.